# Como mostrar un archivo pdf dentro de un DIV, tomado con PHP desde mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

Logré mostrar el contenido de un TXT desde mysql con PHP. con el siguiente codigo.

```
  <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads where file ='notas.txt'";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
   $fileName = $row['file'];
        $fileContents = file_get_contents("uploads/$fileName");
        echo $fileContents;
              
    }
  ?>
```

También lo tengo de esta manera, pero como link

```
<a href="uploads/<?php  echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a>
```

EL txt se carga en la pagina al abrirla. Mi meta es que tengo un menu en la parte izquierda de la pagina, y en la parte derecha planeo mostrar el pdf. Pero solamente cuando de clic en algun boton del menu izquierdo, el pdf cambie en el apartado derecho.
Es decir, depende del boton presionado, se actualice el PDF en el apartado derecho. Como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo como mostrar el archivo desde la la BD, ¿como puedo hacer para que cuando de clic en el href del boton, me muestre el pDF a la derecha ?
Tomando en cuenta que a la derecha tengo un DIV con col de boostrap

Comment: ¿Qué has intentando y qué problemas tienes? Lo que preguntas es más que otra código Javascript. Escuchando los clicks de los elementos podrás mandar a buscar el PDF al servidor y mostrarlo, sin tener que recargar la página.

Answer (score 1):

Hola para hacer eso de que al hacer click se te muestre un pdf tienes que utilizar JS, como ejemplo te propongo un código:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" id="linkView">view file</a>
  <div class="showPDF"></div>
</div>
```

Aqui pues esta tu enlace y luego una caja donde mostrarás el PDF.
El JS tiene que hacer algo como esto (en el ejemplo uso jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#linkView').click(function(){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.width = '100%';
        iframe.height = '700px';
        iframe.src = 'http://localhost/pruebas_stack/files/file1.pdf'; //Aqui iría el src de tu archivo .PDF
        $('.showPDF').append(iframe);
    });
 });
```

Yo me cree una carpeta file y ahi tengo los pdf, como por ejemplo file1.pdf. Tu en tu caso tienes que indicar el directorio donde tienes los pdf, bueno tal cual lo estas haciendo con PHP.
Espero te sirva, saludos